# Linear congruential equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Find all integer solutions $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ that simultaneously satisfy

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle
\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{5}y+\frac{3}{4}z\in\mathbb{Z},\\
\displaystyle
\frac{5}{6}x-\frac{3}{7}y-\frac{1}{2}z\in\mathbb{Z}.\\
\end{array}\right.$$

The numbers are only an example. I'm interested in a systemmatic way of solving this kind of problems. The equations are linear and the coefficients are rational. I tried mapping the problem to linear congruential equations using the unit-fraction common divisors

$$\mathrm{gcd}\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{4},1\right)=\frac{1}{60},\quad
\mathrm{gcd}\left(\frac{5}{6},-\frac{3}{7},-\frac{1}{2},1\right)=\frac{1}{42},$$

to obtain

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
20x+24y+45z\equiv 0\,(\mathrm{mod}\;60),\\
35x-18y-21z\equiv 0\,(\mathrm{mod}\;42).
\end{array}\right.$$

This problem comes from physics and the solutions $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ form a Bravais lattice structure. Physically the ultimate goal is to find the volume of the primitive cell of the lattice. I'm not sure how to proceed. The coefficients of the two congruential equations are not invertible in the $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ rings. Can we do better than enlarging the rings to $\mathbb{Z}_{420}$ and brute-force enumerating all posibilities or are there theories that help?

Comment: This specific example is quite easy to solve, but a general method is a bit trickier.

Comment: What was your method?

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle
\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{5}y+\frac{3}{4}z\in\mathbb{Z},\\
\displaystyle
\frac{5}{6}x-\frac{3}{7}y-\frac{1}{2}z\in\mathbb{Z}.\\
\end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
The $x$ and $z$ terms will not be able to create fifths or sevenths so $y \equiv 0 \pmod{35}$ and so the central terms will generate whole numbers. Now consider the first expression, the $x$ term cannot create any quarters and so $z \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Finally the second expression no forces $x \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$.

So the general solution is $ \color{blue}{(x,y,z) =(6p,35q,4r)}$ for $ p,q,r  \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It solves this specific example. But in general the lattice vectors of the solutions $(x,y,z)$ need not be orthogonal, meaning $x,y,z$ can be linearly coupled to form integers. The problem is that the denominators of the first equation have distinctive prime factors.

Comment: If the denominators share prime factors the solution will involve congreunces of linear combinations of $x,y$ and $z$ for each prime. These can be solved using the chinese remainder theorem & will require considerably more effort.

Comment: Can the primitive cell volume have a simple expression? For one equation, the result is simply the least common multiple of the denominators.